# $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\text{lim}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n-f|dμ=0 \iff \text{lim}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n| dμ=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|dμ $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f_n,f \in  \mathcal{L}^1$ and $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere.
Show that $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\text{lim}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n-f|dμ=0  \iff \underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\text{lim}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n| dμ=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|dμ $

---

let $ε>0$,

**$(\Rightarrow)$**

Because $f_n,f \in  \mathcal{L}^1 \Rightarrow |f_n|,|f|\in \mathcal{L}^1$,
we also have that  $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere, $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\text{lim}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n|-|f|dμ \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n-f|dμ <ε $

so it exists a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n|\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}| f|dμ$ $\:\:\forall n\ge n_0$

$\Rightarrow|\:| f_n|\:|\leq |f|$ $\:\:\forall n\ge n_0$

I consider $g_n=f_{n_0+n}$ so $|g_n|\le |f| , \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $|g_n| \rightarrow  |f| $

so now I can use the dominated convergence theorem, and I have $ \underbrace{ \underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\text{lim}} \int |g_n|}_{\underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\text{lim}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n| dμ}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|dμ $

$(\Leftarrow)$

$|f_n-f|\leq2|f_n|-2|f|\Rightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n-f|dμ\leq 2\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n|dμ-2\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|dμ$

$0\leq\underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\text{lim}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n-f|dμ\leq \underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\text{lim}}(2\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n|dμ-2\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|dμ )\mapsto 0$

---

**Is my solution correct ? If the ideas are correct, how could I improve the solution ?**

Comment: $|f_n - f| \le 2|f_n| - 2|f|$ is not a valid inequality.

Comment: There is no particular reason why you couldn't have $\int |f_n| > \int |f|$ for all $n$ (e.g. $f_n > 0$ yet $f_n \to 0$ almost everywhere) so your reasoning on the first part doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual idea is to use the inequality $|f| + |f_n| - |f - f_n| \ge 0$ and apply Fatou's lemma: since $|f_n| \to |f|$ and $|f - f_n| \to 0$ almost everywhere you obtain
$$\int 2|f| \, d\mu \le \liminf \int |f| + |f_n| - |f- f_n| \, d\mu.$$
You need to be a bit careful with the $\liminf$ since it doesn't obey the usual limit laws, but you do have
$$\liminf \int |f| + |f_n| - |f- f_n| \, d\mu = \int |f| \, d\mu + \int |f| \, d\mu - \limsup \int |f_n - f| \, d\mu$$ because $\int |f_n| \to \int |f|$.  Rearrange to discover $$\limsup \int |f - f_n| \, d\mu \le 0.$$

Comment: Thanks for the help! The ''$(\Rightarrow)$ ''of my proof is correct  ?